# finding and extracting text from a string in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm extracting text from a database, in which are various tags.

For example:

> this is a page of text, there is another [page=5]page[/page] here or
>   you can download this [document=3]document[/document] or this
>   [document=4]document[/document]

I need to find each tag type and replace its content with different text, so in this example whatever the folder/file is for page 5, and the same for whatever documents 3 and 4 would be.

My first thought was to look through the string, initially looking for [page= or [document=, then extract everything after that up to the ], so I'd get the database id for each docoument or page.

Then i could query the database for those document/page id's, and replace [page and [document tags with proper links and their locations.

But I think there must be a more efficient way to achieve this.

Is there a simpler way of extracting the [page and [document values into say an array?

Then I could just loop through that array, do the database querys, and replace what i need?

Comment: Mind sharing your final code to help the next guy? :)

Comment: I've not done it yet, but when i do i'll be sure to post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want rematch. It will return an array of matches.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, and thanks for your blog as well - i often find myself there while looking for a solution to something!